# Weston examples on Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspbian, wayland, weston

I've just successfully compiled and installed Wayland and Weston on my raspberry box (running Raspbian) following these instructions http://wayland.freedesktop.org/raspberrypi.html
However, when I run `weston`, the only program available to run on Wayland is `weston-terminal`.
How can I install other examples?

Thanks,
Giulio

Comment: I don't have enough points to use the proper tags, eg. `weston` and `wayland`

Answer (score 1):

There aren't a lot of applications available for Wayland natively at this point, however there is an X emulation layer (xwayland.so) that can be enabled in your ~/.config/weston.ini file by adding the following lines to the file and restarting weston.

```
[core]
modules=xwayland.so,desktop-shell.so
```

In my experience so far futzing with it, I have had limited success however I have seen screenshots from other people's blog posts showing xwayland happily working so I'm going to posit that given the right circumstances the XWayland layer will give you a pretty usable system.

Comment: hm, doesn't seem to work on the regular install, maybe they are using another install source?